# How much height do you need to hang gymnastic rings?

Tags: calisthenics, rings

I want to start training with rings at my local gym, but the bar I would be hanging them from isn't so high and would mean the length of the straps above the rings would be very short. Would this small amount of slack make the rings behave differently/be detrimental to my training?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you hang the rings with adjustable straps, you should be able to do most strength work by moving them up and down depending on whether you need to be above or below the rings.

If you intend to do gymnastic movements where you swing from below the rings to support (supporting your weight on your arms while you are above the rings), you will probably need more height.

Many people become very strong with limited space and equipment; do the best you can with what you have and it will probably be more than enough.